# c# parsing font error

Tags: c#, parsing, fonts

I have a two window basic system not using System.Windows.Forms but System.Windows.Controls, one of them creates a FontDialog, so I had to include the System.Windows.Forms, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to have the font dialog. In the other window I have a RichTextBox which should use the font/size/style selected in the FontDialog of the other window.

This is the class for the window that creates the FontDialog:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public FontDialog font;

    public Window1(String name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.Text = name;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        font = new FontDialog();
        font.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And here I call the Window1 and try to use its font.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 a = new Window1(this.name);
    a.ShowDialog();

    var cvt = new FontConverter();
    string s = cvt.ConvertToString(a.font.Font);

    Console.Out.WriteLine("Value is: " + s);

    System.Windows.Media.FontFamily g = (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily) cvt.ConvertFromString(s);

    if (g != null)
    {
         this.textBox2.FontFamily = g;
    }
}
```

It outputs exactly what is selected in the FontDialog, but then it crashes at the line "this.textBox2.FontFamily = g;":

```
Value is: Microsoft Sans Serif; 8,25pt
'_.NetworkingGT_Incrementer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt-BR_31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.resources.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'_.NetworkingGT_Incrementer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt-BR_b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.resources.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

Comment: Aside from your Window1 being a bit ugly, split your lines up and debug. Where exactly do you get the exception: is it in `cvt.ConvertFromString()`, in the `FontFamily =`, in...? Also, is it the comma in the font size that's throwing you?

Comment: @lc. it crashes at this.textBox2.FontFamily = g;, if I comment it then it doesn't crash

Comment: Ok, so what do you get out of `cvt.ConvertFromString(s)`? Note you're using `as` *without* checking if you get a null result...not sure why you don't just cast.

Comment: I just saw this piece of code online then used it. I changed it to cast and added an if clause and edited the question to be consistent

Comment: Ok, still doesn't solve your problem though, right? Debug through it and see what you get out of `cvt.ConvertFromString(s)`

Comment: Really stupid solution, I posted an answer thanks @lc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
var cvt = new FontConverter();

string s = cvt.ConvertToString(a.font.Font);

Console.Out.WriteLine("Value is: " + s);

System.Windows.Media.FontFamily g = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(s);

Console.Out.WriteLine("Value is: " + g.ToString());

this.textBox2.FontFamily = g;
```

Both outputs are equal.